# CSS div expanding without content

Tags: css, html

Im currently working on a new website, and I've got a problem.
I've got 2 div's next to eachother, one with content and one with a background image.

The div with content is allready auto expanding with the content in it

Now, the one with the background image is just for design, there is no content in it and I want it to expand automaticly with the one with content in so they both have the same height.

Here are 2 screenshots to make my question abit more clear.

[view from Photoshop](http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/nyfqzdrymbru.png)

[View from browser](http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/gijopfmhpkgl.png)

HTML:

```
        <div id="bubble">
            Stad Turnhout
        </div>

        <div id="date">
            <span class="created">created</span><br/><span class="date">okt<br/>2011</span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="slash">
    </div>

    <div class="textfield">
        <p class="text">
            Text goes in here
        </p>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#slash {
float:left;
width:20px;
height:auto;
background:url(images/slash.jpg) no-repeat, url(images/socialbg.jpg) repeat;}


.textfield {
padding:25px;
width:269px;
height:auto;
float:right;
background:url(images/point.jpg) no-repeat, #FFF;}
```

I've been trying several things, and tried finding something on google, but nothing was useful.
Any idea's on how I can fix this with HTML/CSS?

Thanks

EDIT: added my code

Comment: show us your html and css or create a jsfiddle demo

Comment: check this page http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background_shorthand2

Comment: @Venkat w3schools is horrible resource try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to make two side by side div's always the same height AND expandable. You can give the two elements a parent wrapper and then set a height on that wrapper, then give the two child divs 100% height. Their height will then be controlled by the wrapper's fixed height.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="slash"></div>

        <div class="textfield">
            <p class="text">
                Text goes in here
            </p>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .wrapper {
        height: 350px;
    }
    #slash, .textfield {
        height: 100%
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer StewD, but its not working properly.
I've found a solution but I can't seem to implement it into my code
http://jsfiddle.net/9sVKJ/

Comment: I've got it to work. For people with the same problem, check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/9sVKJ/